# Using cell address of a private sub inside a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a Private Sub Worksheet_Change to localize any change within a range of cells. After a change has been made and some requirements are fulfilled, I require a textbox so the user may or may not modify such changes. Inside this textbox I do not know how to refer to the original cell address used in the Private Sub.

I have tried to use global variables but it does not work.

```
Global A as Range
' Code for a specific worksheet 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal T As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("Ag5:KL205")
     If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(T.address)) Is Nothing Then

A = T

' Code for Conditions

Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
End

End Sub

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Code inside UserForm1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then

TextValue1 = TextBox1.Value
A.Value = TextValue1
```

I want that inside that textbox, the cell to change is the one which activated the code in the Private Sub. I've tried using ActiveCell.Value, but the thing is that if the user presses "enter" the active cell for the text box is the one below. If the user presses "right arrow", the active cell is the one next to it. I've tried to specify the code to the specific action that the user might do, but I haven't had any luck in that either.

Comment: if it is not absolutely required to unload `UserForm1` then why not use `UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = T.Address`  : `UserForm1.Hide` in Change event. And in Command button click `Range(TextBox2.Value).Value = TextValue1`

Comment: To create a global variable, you must declare it in a normal module at its top like this `Public A as Range`. If you declare it in a sheet module or a userform, or a class, it will be restraint to that one only.
Also , since A is a range , you must write `Set A = T`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I didn't know you could make use of UserForms without Unloading it. I still have a problem with the line
`Range(TextBox2.Value).Value = TextValue1`
The error 1004 is within the Range method with the object _Global. 

I've also tried tu creat the public variable A and set it to T.Address and in the command button use
`Range(A).Value = TextValue1`
or 
`A.Value = TextValue1`

but none of them works